# strange division operator in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I am new to Groovy.

why this throws exception on runtime:

```
int[] a = [1,2,3,4,5]
int lo=0
int hi=4

int x = a[(lo+hi)/2]
assert x == 3
```

while these are ok:

```
int x = a[(int)(lo+hi)/2]
```

and

```
int i = (lo+hi)/2
int x = a[i]
```

Comment: Please tell us the exception.

Comment: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: [I.getAt() is applicable for argument types: (java.math.BigDecimal) values: [2]
Possible solutions: getAt(groovy.lang.Range), getAt(java.lang.Integer), getAt(java.util.Collection), getAt(groovy.lang.ObjectRange), getAt(groovy.lang.IntRange), getAt(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In groovy a division results in a `BigDecimal` if the operands are of type `Integer`, `Long`, `BigInteger` or `BigDecimal`:

See for instance [this tutorial](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Math):

> The division operators "/" and "/=" produce a Double result if either operand is either Float or Double and a **BigDecimal result otherwise** (both operands are any combination of Integer, Long, BigInteger, or BigDecimal).
>
> [...]
>
> For example
>
> ```
> 1/2 == new java.math.BigDecimal("0.5");
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> Integer division can be performed on the integral types **by casting the result of the division**. For example:
>
> ```
> assert (int)(3/2) == 1I;
> ```

Comment: All the numeric types also support the `intdiv()` method which allows you to do integer division without casting, e.g. `assert 3.intdiv(2) == 1I`

Comment: what type is that "2" constant as the divider for this case?